# how do you compare three arrays of data and return a matched value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have this code

```
var a = 'ps';
var b = 'xbox';
var c = 'nintendo';
var d = 'dindendo';

var platformIcon = [a,b,c,d];
var platform = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var slug = ['a', 'b'];
var slug1 = new Set(slug);
var difference = [...new Set(platform.filter(x => slug1.has(x)))];

console.log(difference);
```

i was able to find the match of slug and platform but when it comes down to match an array(platformIcon) which contains variables with the same name as of the value of the slug and return the matched value;i can not figure it out.
i am trying to do something like this-
if(difference == any matched name from the platform icon) then the matched value(regardless of the type) should be returned. e.g- difference = a,b? then the value of platformIcon should return the value with the same name.

so far, i was able to do this and stuck -

```
var differenceIcon = [...new Set(platformIcon.filter(x => slug1.has(x)))];
console.log(differenceIcon);
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does the following mean?

"when it comes down to match an array(platformIcon) with variable with the same name as of slug and return the matched value[...]"

Comment: my bad! Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an object map which has slug name and platform name linked together.

```js
const platformMap = {
  "a": "ps",
  "b": "xbox",
  "c": "nintendo",
  "d": "dintendo"
};
const slugs = ["a", "b"];
const result = slugs.map(slug => platformMap[slug]);
result.forEach(r => {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  const txt = document.createTextNode(r);
  li.appendChild(txt);
  document.querySelector("#platforms").appendChild(li);
});
//console.log(result);
```

```html
<ul id="platforms"></ul>
```

Comment: oh sweet! This works smoothly!
if you don't mind me asking,how would you create ul>li element based on the number of slugs there will be?
would you,like,loop over the slugs and create elements based on the slugs length?

Comment: Sure, you could loop over `result` building a li with the platform name and appending it to a UL, see above